# Cookie Middleware without Identity ASP.NET Core v2

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to authenticate without using identity. I have found a few articles describing how to do it in other versions however nothing for ASP.NET Core 2.

Below is what I have cobbled together. But when it gets to SignInAsync an exception is thrown `InvalidOperationException: No authentication handler is configured to handle the scheme: MyCookieMiddlewareInstance`

```
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddCookieAuthentication("MyCookieMiddlewareInstance", o =>
        {
            o.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login/");
            o.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Account/Forbidden/");

        });
        services.AddAuthentication();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.UseAuthentication();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Login()
    {

        var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "joe nobody")
            };
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "MyCookieMiddlewareInstance");
        var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

        //blows up on the following statement:
        //InvalidOperationException: No authentication handler is configured to handle the scheme: MyCookieMiddlewareInstance
        await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync("MyCookieMiddlewareInstance", principal); 

        return View();
    }
```

There is a Microsoft document for asp.net core v1.x (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie) however the IApplicationBuilder.UseCookieAuthentication() is depreciated in v2 and haven't found any solution.

Comment: I'm not setup to try anything 2.0 related,but I'm very interested in your question since it will affect me. If you look at some of their unit tests, you may be able to get an idea of at least what objects you should call:   https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/pull/1119/commits/2bdfdb3220b3aca7513455652617af5685d5293c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like there are a few breaking changes with Auth 2.0 (https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/232)

The setup was correct however I needed to do two things:

1. Use `HttpContext.SignInAsync()` (`using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication`) instead of `HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync()`
2. Use `"AuthenticationTypes.Federation"` as the authentication type 
   (Note: other values don't seem to work and blank will result in the user name being set and IsAuthenticated to false)

   `var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "AuthenticationTypes.Federation");`

Below is the corrected code

In Startup.cs

```
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddCookieAuthentication("MyCookieMiddlewareInstance", o =>
        {
            o.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login/");
            o.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Account/Forbidden/");
        });
        services.AddAuthentication();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

In Controller

```
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
    //...
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login()
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "joe nobody")
        };
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "AuthenticationTypes.Federation");
        var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
        await HttpContext.SignInAsync("MyCookieMiddlewareInstance", principal);

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Rather than hard-coding `AuthenticationTypes.Federation` you should probably reference `TokenValidationParameters.DefaultAuthenticationType`, which is hard-coded to that value in [`Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens`](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/blob/master/src/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens/TokenValidationParameters.cs)... which, for some reason, is hidden away in the AzureAD extensions project. Clear as mud...